# Java Timezone Conversion Issue Between Server and Local Environment

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, java-17

I'm encountering an issue with time zone conversion between my server and local environment. I've an entity Account with field accountCreationDate as OffsetDateTime.
Here are the details:

- Server Timestamp: 2023-12-20T13:37:17.288582240Z[GMT]
- Local Timezone:Europe/Tirana
- Server Timezone Offset: 0 (GMT)
- Local Timezone Offset:3600 (GMT+01:00)
  When I run this in Database "SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;" RESULT: "+01:00"

In my code, I'm attempting to transform timestamps
between the server and local environments:

```
if (accountRequest.getAccountCreationDate() != null) {
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(accountRequest.getAccountCreationDate());

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime cetDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = cetDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();

requestTransformer.setAccountDateCreation(offsetDateTime);
}
```

Response Transformer:

```
if (pamUserAccount.getAccountDateCreation() != null) {
OffsetDateTime cetDateTime = pamUserAccount.getAccountDateCreation();

LocalDateTime localDateTime = cetDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)); // GMT+01:00
long epochMillis = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .toInstant()
        .toEpochMilli();

response.setAccountDateCreation(epochMillis);
```

}
Locally works as excepted, with this as timestamp 1542754800000 which is converted as 2018-11-21T00:00+01:00 OffsetDateTime and return the result.
However, on the server, I'm getting NONE. I expect to receive the same row of data. Any insights into what might be going wrong here?

I check and this aswell:

```
 pamUserAccount.getAccountDateCreation();
```

Locally I got: 2018-11-21T01:00+01:00

In server I got: 2018-11-21T00:00Z

Answer (score 5):

Pass a `ZoneId` to [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) instead of a fixed `ZoneOffset`. When you pass a fixed `ZoneOffset`, you are restricting the calculation to exactly one zone offset, but when you pass a `ZoneId`, the zone offset will automatically be adjusted as per the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Change your code to use `ZoneId.of("Europe/Tirana")` instead of `ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)`.

You can make some further improvements to your code e.g. instead of using

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime cetDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
```

you could use

```
ZonedDateTime cetDateTime = Instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Tirana"));
```

Similarly, instead of using

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = cetDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
```

you could use

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = cetDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Tirana"));
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I've tried that and still I've the same issue

Comment: ++ First time seeing zone `Europe/Tirana`

Comment: nice and clean response, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
private OffsetDateTime getOffsetDateTimeFromMillis(Long epochMillis) {
    ZoneOffset systemDefaultOffset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
    if (systemDefaultOffset.getTotalSeconds() == 0) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        ZonedDateTime adjustedDateTime = zonedDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(adjustedDateTime.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    } else {
        return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your own solution. It’s unnecessarily complicated and probably has a bug. If you can’t avoid getting a `long` count of milliseconds, I think you just want `return Instant .ofEpochMilli(epochMillis) .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .toOffsetDateTime();` (and no `if` statement).  Declare the parameter as a primitive `long` (lower case `l`). If your time zone has summer time (DST; as Europe/Tirana has), you need the offset that is valid for `epochMillis`, not the current offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your time into your output from sql to timestamp, and convert it easly in your code java.